# How to receive incoming call when app is in background implemented using quickblox-iOS framework

Tags: ios, voip, quickblox

I've integrated the quickblox framework into my iOS project.

I've added the VoIP capability on background mode of plist file.

But I can't get incoming call when app is in background.

Any idea for this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

QuickBlox officially recommend to use Audio, AirPlay and Picture in Picture background mode enabled in their official documentation

[image: Background Mode]

Here is the [link](http://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-webrtc-ios#Background_mode) for quickblox-ios webrtc implementation.

In my experience you can stream only audio when your app is in background, and if app is not in active state you would have to send push notification to your user to accept call.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Will try it and get back to here soon.